# sourceOne.peek is not a function

Tags: javascript

Can't figure this one out and the error is too vague to get any relevant results. Most of the time when I get this error its because I'm trying to use an array method on a function or something similar.

I'm running through Grider's DS&A and I'm on the queue exercise. I have veered off from it a bit so that I can understand what is happening and why. Here's what I have:

```
let x = [1,2,3,4,5];
let y = [6,7,8,9,10];

class Queue {
  constructor() {
    this.data = [];
  }

  add(record) {
    this.data.unshift(record);
  }

  remove() {
    return this.data.pop();
  }

  peek() {
    return this.data[this.data.length - 1];
  }
}

function weave(sourceOne, sourceTwo) {          
  return sourceOne.peek();
}
```

For now, I'm just trying to pass in x, via sourceOne parameter and return the last item in the x array via my peek() method/function. But I'm getting the error:

```
sourceOne.peek is not a function
```

I'm not really even looking for a static answer here, more looking for the "why". It doesn't seem to be a scope issue. I'm sure this is a fundamentally simple issue, due to my lack of understanding, but I could use at least a pointer in the right direction for me to research, as "is not a function" is one of those super-vague errors, difficult to nail down. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where does `weave` get called?

Comment: First, do a console.log(sourceOne) to see what object your function is receiving.

Comment: I see now. You ar missconcepting. x is a simple array, you created a class, so you need to pass a instance of it get it? You are calling class Queue methods on a ArrayObject class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to receive your array at the constructor to fill inside data array. Try this:

```
let x = [1,2,3,4,5];
let y = [6,7,8,9,10];

class Queue {
  constructor(array) {
    this.data = array;
  }

  add(record) {
    this.data.unshift(record);
  }

  remove() {
    return this.data.pop();
  }

  peek() {
    return this.data[this.data.length - 1];
  }
}

source = new Queue(x);

function weave(sourceOne, sourceTwo) {          
  return sourceOne.peek();
}

weave(source, {})
```

Comment: Of course! I'm still trying to process 'classes.' Naturally I need to make x an instance of the Queue class. Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: It's normal, don't worry :)    a great source of knowledge is MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) https://developer.mozilla.org